# What properties can be changed to maximize a p-n diodes effectiveness at higher temperatures?

Tags: diodes, design, semiconductors, circuits

So the reverse bias breakdown voltage of a diode gets smaller as temperature increases.
What can be done to change that?

Can the concentration of dopants of the p or n layers be changed to make this happen?

Will the resistance of the loop that the diode is in affect the breakdown voltage?

What other factors can affect the breakdown voltage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it smells too much like a homework question. Asking a question about your homework is OK and we will try to help **but** we will not do the homework for you or provide direct answers. **You** will have to show what you have tried to answer the questions. Look up the principles and equations that define the breakdown voltage, what can be learned from that?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main principles that allow a diode to go into breakdown:

- *Avalanche* breakdown: When the electric field in the depletion region gets too strong, charges can gain enough kinetic energy to generate more electron-hole pairs. These new charges can potentially gain enough kinetic energy to excite other electron-hole pairs. It causes a multiplication effect, called *avalanching*. It should be noted that if no charges are present inside the depletion region, then the diode will also not avalanche. However, a single charge can disrupt that. This effect is exploited in for example Single-Photon Counting, where a *single photon* can generate an electron-hole pair, starting a surge of current that can be measured.
- *Zener* breakdown: It is possible that at the P-N junction, the conduction band of the N-region gets very close to the valence band of the P-region (see image on the right - Wikipedia).

  [image: Wikipedia image]

  This breakdown happens usually at high doping levels. It is by my knowledge mainly exploited by Zener diodes for lower Zener-breakdown voltages.

It should be noted that Zener breakdown happens faster for increasing temperature as more charges become excited (also reducing the band gap this way) that can tunnel. Avalanche breakdown happens later, as the heat will increase the number of collisions of moving charges, making it harder to build up kinetic energy.

In both cases, reducing the doping levels will reduce breakdown effects. For *avalanche*, the depletion width will increase, causing the electric field to decrease (\$|E| \sim \Phi / w\$). The built-in potential will decrease as well, leading to a lower internal potential. *Zener* breakdown will also be reduced, as the built-in potential decreases.

Another way of reducing breakdown effects is by increasing the depletion width in other ways. For example, you can apply a smooth doping profile, or move to a PIN diode altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The tendency that the band gap gets smaller with temperature follows directly from the physics of a semiconductor; you can't change that *principle*. You can use other, higher-band gap materials than your usual Si to combat the issue, but I don't think you'll ever change the fact that there's a temperature term in the formula that defines the probability that a certain energy level is occupied.

That is given by the [Fermi-Dirac distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics#Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_distribution), which inconveniently has the absolute temperature in the exponent:

$$  \bar{n}_i = \frac{1}{e^{(\epsilon_i-\mu) / k T} + 1} $$

The Wikipedia article linked to above has a nice graph on what happens to the distribution of occupied states in rising temperature:

By [Krishnavedala](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Krishnavedala) - Own work, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=15478733)

You want that decrease to be as sharp as possible to get a well-defined, wide band gap. You really can't do anything about the math here.